# Where is the storage location of Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, storage

I have installed Ubuntu terminal(Ubuntu app) in Windows 10, I have enabled the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

The problem is that I cannot find the path where the files that I am using are getting stored. How do I find them?

I want to install an application through Ubuntu terminal and find its location in my laptop.

Does the Ubuntu application create a folder for storing the files in my computer?
If I create a directory where is its location set?

Answer (score 4):

Your Linux file system is stored in a hidden folder which you’ll find stored in a hidden folder. To access it, open File Explorer and plug the following address into the address bar:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages
```

In this folder, double-click the folder for Ubuntu. The folder name will be beginning with

```
CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu...
```

In other words, the files are stored at:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\DISTRO_FOLDER\LocalState\rootfs
```

## Note

Don’t Modify Linux Files With Windows Tools
Quoting from [Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

> Creating/changing Linux files in your Appdata folder from Windows will likely result in data corruption and/or damage your Linux environment requiring you to uninstall & reinstall your distro!