# What is the directory path of the Ubuntu app in Windows10?

Tags: 18.04

I'm using the Windows10 machine and installed the Ubuntu app which is available in the Microsoft Store.  I would like to ask help about the directory path of my home directory.
[Ubuntu 18.04 on Microsoft Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ie9G.png)

Comment: I have answered a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/a/1199245/890892

Comment: Thank you for the help. I got it now.